# convert NDB urlsafe key strings to googledatastore.Key

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to be able to share `ndb.key.urlsafe()` strings between ndb and [googledatastore python library](https://developers.google.com/datastore/)

- Does anyone have a conversion example to constuct a `googledatastore.Key` from a `ndb.key.urlsafe()` string?
- And, an example to build a urlsafe string from a `googledatastore.Key` would be nice as well

I've also made a [github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/44)

EDIT: Note that googledatastore has SerializeToString() and FromString() but that is protobuff based and doesn't accept ndb key strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked a colleague to extract the code out of the appengine library. This is the result: https://github.com/transceptor-technology/dbWrapper/blob/master/gcdKeyNdbKey.py

It exposes the following functions:

`from gcdKeyNdbKey import gcdKeyFromUrlSafe
from gcdKeyNdbKey import urlSafeFromGcdKey`

Answer (score 1):

What about ndb.to_old_key(), isn't that exactly what you want?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_urlsafe

Comment: I want to be able to serialize and deserialize it to a string so that I can send representations of keys to another server. I'm not sure what to do with old keys? To be clear `googledatastore` is not app-engine code.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to have to do a little work yourself as Cloud Datastore and ndb talk in different formats. Since ndb's `urlsafe` is its own function (a base64 encoding plus some formatting stuff), I would recommend using ndb to read the urlsafe format, then convert it to a Cloud Datastore key:

```
urlsafeKey = '....'
# First, let ndb deserialize the key.
ndbKey = ndb.Key(urlsafe=urlsafeKey)
# Rebuild the Cloud Datastore key using the path from ndb.
cloudKey = googledatastore.datastore_v1_pb2.Key()
for pair in ndbKey.pairs():
  googledatastore.helper.add_key_path(cloudKey, pair[0], pair[1])
```

If you want to go from a googledatastore Key to an ndb serialized key, you could do the same thing but in reverse.

```
pairs = []
for path_element in cloudKey.path_elements:
  if path_element.HasField('name'):
    id_or_name = path_element.name
  else:
    id_or_name = path_element.id
  pairs.append((path_element.kind, id_or_name))
ndbKey = ndb.Key(pairs=pairs)
```

**Disclaimer**: I didn't actually run the code, so you may need to mess with it a little.

Comment: That would require including the ndb library in the backend system. Hmmm

Comment: Yes it would. If you want you can try to pull out only the relevant code. The source for ndb lives here: https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/source/browse/ndb/key.py. Also, there is a current Feature Request to port ndb to use Cloud Datastore: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/2 In this case, you could just use ndb on directly.

Comment: Yes I know, Im Obeleh in that discussion. I've tried looking at the ndb code for serializing but the code ins't really straight forward